# Changing the color of the filtered or sorted column in grid kendo ui

Tags: jquery, colors, kendo-ui

Hi I want to change the background color of the column (of the kendo ui grid) that has been filtered or sorted . I want to change the color of the whole column not just the header.
Does anyone knows how to get to this with a css class?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the game on this, but I had this requirement in an application I'm building as well and figured I'd share a solution.  Highlighting cells is the easy part - getting into Kendo to figure out *which* cells to highlight is the trick.  I used @Atanas Korchev's response and modified it to keep it from highlighting the Kendo footer:

```
var filterObj = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter;
if (filterObj.arguments && filterObj.arguments[0]) {
    filterObj.arguments[0].filters.forEach(function(val) {
        var index = $(".k-header[data-field='" + val.field + "']").index();
        $("#grid tr[role='row']").find("td:eq(" + index + ")").css("background-color", "red");
    });
}
```

Big caveat - I completely reverse engineered this on my own without consulting the Kendo docs (which are a maze at best) so this is something that you can't *guarantee* to keep working in future releases.  We're fixed here on our version of Kendo for the time being at least, so it works for us (for now).  Also, I didn't spend enough time to really understand why there's only ever one object in the "arguments" list - you may need to loop through that at some point as well to pull out those filters if your use-case or configuration is somehow different (again, in my local scenario, it doesn't appear to ever exceed 1 argument, which makes me a little nervous).  It's just one more .forEach though anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can find the n-th cell (corresponding to the index of the filtered column) and set their CSS style:

```
$("#grid tr").find("td:eq(1)").css('background', 'grey');
```

This will set the background of every second cell to grey. Here is a live demo:

http://jsbin.com/ixozad/1/edit

Comment: I am not sure that you understood my question. At first the grid will be in same color, but then after filtering or sorting the specified column I want to change the color of the same column

Comment: I understood your question perfectly well. The code I've shown can be used to set the color of any column (filtered or sorted). You need to find the column index yourself though.

Comment: That was my point I don't know how to find the index, because the grid has like 10 columns and all of them are sortable and filterable, and the user will be able to choose which ever column he wants to sort/filter and than I want that one (the picked one) to change the background-color :/